# How to make a table fit the window height in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am New to VBA. I have a table with 4 columns and almost 2000 rows and it is displayed in a 3 column Word layout. My problem is that the last rows of the 3 columns are not always on one height as shown in the image (Masked the personal data with the white font in cells). [Image of the Table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUSzp.png)

I think a solution would be to set the height of the rows with 2-lines to 0.54cm and the 1-line rows to 0.27cm. I did this manually and it worked. I am looking for a macro to achieve this. The below code will provide an understanding of what I am trying to do.

```
Sub height ()

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
     'this automatically sets the 2-line rows to 0.53cm and the 1-line rows to 0.25cm

For Each row in Rows
   If Row.RowHeight < 0.5cm Then 
      Row.RowHeight = 0.27cm
   Else Row.RowHeight = 0.54cm
   End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

I know that this code cant work but i think it shows you what i want to do.

Comment: `Row.RowHeight` won't return a useful value unless the row has been set to an exact height. You would do better to change the line spacing for the text so that it results in the cell heights you want.

Answer (score 0):

As `Row.RowHeight` won't return a useful value unless the row has been set to an exact height you can change the line spacing for the text so that the required cell heights are achieved automatically.

The code below assumes that the table you want to adjust is the first one in the document.

```
Sub AdjustLineSpacingForTable()
   Dim reqdLineSpacing As Single
   'start with the height of a double height cell
   reqdLineSpacing = CentimetersToPoints(0.54)
   With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
      'table cells have padding top and bottom so we need to subtract that from the required height
      reqdLineSpacing = reqdLineSpacing - (.TopPadding + .BottomPadding)
      'now we can adjust the text spacing
      With .Range.ParagraphFormat
         'ensure there is no additional spacing on the paragraphs
         .SpaceAfter = 0
         .SpaceBefore = 0
         'set line spacing to an exact amount
         .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
         .LineSpacing = reqdLineSpacing / 2
      End With
   End With
End Sub
```